# How to link login user to post that he created?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and I made the tutorial on django site. I thought that I could link user to poll that he created but I'm struggling with it. When I'm logged in and creating a poll I can't see user name. In database column `author_id` has value `null`. I would appreciate every help.

Here is my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from django.contrib import auth
# Create your models here.

User = auth.get_user_model()

class Question(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text

class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

forms.py:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'

class CreatePollForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)
```

and views.py

```
class CreatePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreatePollForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pollapp:index')
    template_name = 'polls/createPoll.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `CreatePollForm` only assigns the `question_text` field, you need to assign the `author` in code. A `CreateView` is a `FormView` which does the saving of the form in its `form_valid()` method. So in your `CreateView`, you want to override that method:

```python
# in class CreatePoll
def form_valid(self, form):
    question = form.save(commit=False)  # fetch the new question, don't save
    question.author = self.request.user  # assign the user
    question.save()  # now save
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

It isn't clear how you could end up with a `null` value for the `author_id`, that should have raised an `IntegrityError`. Are you sure you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` in the current state?

Comment: Thank you! It works now ;) I've ran makemigrations and migrate in current state and it worked fine.